# How to call internal dataset by a string in R package

Tags: r

I have included a few internal data sets during building a local R package such as `data_abc, data_cdj, ..., data_mnp`. Then I am attempting to write a function to call one of these datasets depending on the user's input argument `p` which will `abc`, `cdj`, `...`, `mnp` such as:

```
get_data <- function(p) {
       use_data <- paste0('data_', 'p')
       ...
       return(use_data)
}
```

Since `use_data <- paste0('data_', 'p')` is a string, my question is how to make the function return the internal data such as `data_mnp` if `p = 'mnp'`.

Comment: Have a look at `get` e.g. `get(use_data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how you need to do it, but I'd love to be corrected.

```r
get_data <- function(p) {

    data_name = paste0( "data_", p )


    # check first that it exists in your package:
    ns <- getNamespace("your.package.name")
    if(!exists(data_name, where=ns, inherits=FALSE)) {
        stop( "a data set with suffix ", p, " does not exist!")
    }

    return( get( data_name, where=ns, inherits=FALSE ) )

}
```